# Google Maps Javascript API not loading closest zoom level?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Today I noticed that the closest available zoom level of satellite imagery was removed in a particular area (it may affect other areas but I am just focussing on one area that is definitely affected). Two days ago level 20 was available, now only level 19.

MaxZoomService still says the closest available zoom at this location is 20. But when map is at level 19, pressing the + zoom button does not increase zoom to level 20.

Is there are reason why I cannot zoom to level 20 when it says it's available?

Some theoretical explanations (all unconfirmed) include:

1. Zoom level 20 was recently removed but the MaxZoomService has not been updated and is showing the old value
2. Level 20 is temporarily broken at this location and will be restored soon (e.g. perhaps they are reprocessing the imagery tiles for this level?)

(I don't think there's confusion with available depth for top-down vs Oblique because both are locked to level 19).

Updates:

- Map Tiles at level 20 that were previously loading still exist at the old URLs, they are just not loaded in the Javascript API Map. Perhaps this lends weight to the explanation that it's just a temporary issue with the service which lists available imagery layers?
- Seems to be an issue globally, not an isolated geographic area
- Changing to an earlier version of Google Maps Javascript API (e.g. adding ?v=3.29) does not appear to resolve the problem

See live example: https://jsfiddle.net/3qojzt76/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      var map;
      
      var latlng = {lat: 37.8768101, lng: -122.2813413}
      
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
          tilt: 0,
          center: latlng,
          zoom: 19
        });
        
        var mapZoomService = new google.maps.MaxZoomService()
        
        mapZoomService.getMaxZoomAtLatLng(latlng, function(MaxZoomResult){
            
            if(google.maps.MaxZoomStatus.OK){
                alert('map.getZoom(): '+map.getZoom()+', MaxZoomResult.zoom: ' + MaxZoomResult.zoom)
            }else{
                alert('Error: in google.maps.MaxZoomService().getMaxZoomAtLatLng()')
            }
        })
        
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Interesting question. The documentation doesn't provide much help. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maxzoom

Comment: We just noticed this error today too. For now I'm going to work around by testing the zoom level after I try to set it.

Comment: Same thing is happening in our environment. It was working fine on Friday, stopped working sometime Saturday. Hope their internal issue resolves soon?

Comment: Experiencing this problem as well, all over areas of New Mexico, Texas and Oklahoma (probably global). Used to be able to zoom to 20+, now limited to 19. If anyone finds out, would really like an explanation!

Comment: Official investigation tracked at: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/71715009

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This was a bug with Google Maps Javascript API and has been resolved by Google, as per https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/71715009

Answer (score 2):

Yes, True this was a bug previously, now it is working fine. Some modification has been done by Google. for that time being it is broken the same issue I faced now it is resolved. one more thing I noticed when I set a property of the map

```
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
      tilt: 0,
      center: latlng,
      zoom: 20 // look I set it 20
    });
```

it is still not going in a maximum depth.
https://jsfiddle.net/Negirox/3qojzt76/8/
see in above JSfiddle given by @python1981

But when I set it 21 its's going to max level depth but MaxZoomResult.zoom is still showing 20.

```
   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
      tilt: 0,
      center: latlng,
      zoom: 21 // look I set it 21
    });
```

Correct me If I am wrong.

Comment: I can also (still) replicate the issue you raised. Would you consider creating a separate issue for this to draw more attention to it? Or I'll do it if you prefer...

Comment: Ok I will create

Comment: i added it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48740528/google-maps-javascript-api-not-loading-closest-zoom-level-with-maximum-zoom